# Javascript scheduler library

Tags: gratis, open-source, javascript, widget

I am looking for a JavaScript scheduler/calendar library.
The one that resembles the most to what I am needing is [KendoUI's scheduler](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/scheduler/index) but I am interested in something that is free of charge.

I am interested in making an app that will allow people to set and see their schedule per day/week/month and would be great if it could provide a way for someone for viewing the schedule of all the employees.
(Think about doctors setting their patients appointments and the administrator being able to see the whole schedules of all doctors).

I have found some libraries like this but the problem is that all of them come with either a subscription or a fee. Perhaps I am not using the correct keywords when I search for them.
Any pieces of advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Syncfusion [ejSchedule](http://js.syncfusion.com/demos/web/#!/azure/schedule/defaultfunctionalities) control is an option.

The whole product is available for free through the [community license](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.

Answer (score 0):

One library that you may be interested in is called "FullCalendar". It's open-source and available on GitHub. It's simple to use and has demo's which you can use to help learn how it works. It's well documented and being actively updated.

## [FullCalender](http://fullcalendar.io/) ([open-source](https://github.com/fullcalendar))

> #### A JavaScript event calendar. Customizable and open source.
>
> FullCalendar is a drag-n-drop jQuery plugin for displaying events on a full-sized calendar.
>
> [image: FullCalender UI]